# Is there ADASYN-N implementation for Python

Tags: python

I would like to apply ADASYN-N to my data, but I can't find any implementation of it for Python. I have been reading the source code of ADASYN form imblearn but can't find a way to change the distance metric to Value Difference Metric. If I have understood correctly ADASYN-N uses Value Difference Metric to find the nearest neighbor.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ruinian/an-introduction-to-adasyn-with-code-1383a5ece7aa That one?

Comment: Thank you, but I think that article covers only basic ADASYN.